# How to find an orthonormal basis for $ P_{2}(\mathbb R)$ equipped with the inner product $\langle f,g\rangle =f(-1)g(-1)+f(0)g(0)+f(1)g(1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, inner-products

Given $ P_{2}(\mathbb R)$ the vector space of real polynomials of degree less than or equal to 2 equipped with the inner product $$\langle f,g\rangle=f(-1)g(-1)+f(0)g(0)+f(1)g(1).$$ How would I use the Gram-Schmidt process to find an orthonormal basis ?

Comment: The vector space of real polynomials has infinite dimension; Gram-Schmidt will not give you a result in a finite time.

Comment: @Bib-lost Look again. The polynomial space in question is $P_2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: I would guess $P_2$ is the subspace of order maximum 2.

Comment: What exactly don’t you understand about how to apply G-S to this space?

Comment: @mathreadler yes thats right.

Comment: Projection which is used in Gram Schmidt algorithm is defined with respect to the inner product, so start with an arbitrary basis for $P_2(\mathbb R)$, express the projection in terms of inner products and then carry out the calculations.

Comment: I would really appreciate an answer

Comment: Before you can get an answer, you must clarify @ amd's question:  *what* don't you understand about how to use Gram–Schmidt?  It's an algorithm, the application of which in this case @mathreadler has described.

Comment: I only know how to use gram Schmidt with vectors and I know for polynomials it included integration but because this space is equipped with this inner product I am not sure what to integrate

Comment: So your problem is dat you do not know how to calculate the inner product of two polynomials?

Comment: As @mathreadler says, Gram–Schmidt inherently involves neither Euclidean vectors nor integration; it involves only taking inner products.  We have a familiar inner product on Euclidean vectors, and a familiar inner product on $C([0, 1])$ (or on the restriction of $P_2(\mathbb R)$ there) coming from integration, but there's nothing special about them.  Just substitute this new inner product where you would have used the old ones.

Comment: @Bib-lost, it sounds like the problem is not realising that there is an inner product to be computed at all; @ aprilanalysis refers to Gram–Schmidt for polynomials as involving integration, which suggests that he or she has internalised a particular inner product as a black-box operation, without realising its significance.

Comment: Integration is just one form of inner product that can be defined for functions. In this case the inner product is instead a pairwise product of pointwise values.

Comment: In the solution they take v1= 1 and then say that w1= 1/sqrt(3). I am very unsure about where the sqrt(3) comes from.

Comment: To get started, you need a spanning set (preferably a basis) for the inner product space to apply the Gram-Schmidt process (and get an orthonormal basis).  So choose a convenient basis for the real polynomials of degree at most two.

Answer (score 4):

Take any basis, for instance the canonical basis $(1, X, X^2)$

First normalise $1$ :

We have $\langle 1,1\rangle = 1+1+1 = 3$ so the normalised vector is $e_1 = {1\over \sqrt{3}}$

Now find the part of $X$ orthogonal to $1\over \sqrt{3}$. That's easy since $\langle 1,X \rangle = 0$

And normalise $X$ : $$\langle X,X\rangle = 1+0+1 = 2$$ so the normalised vector is $$e_2={X\over \sqrt 2}$$

Finally find the part of $X^2$ orthogonal to $span(1,X)$, ie :
$$\begin{align}X^2 - \langle X^2 ,{X\over \sqrt2}\rangle{X\over \sqrt 2} - \langle X^2, {1\over \sqrt 3}\rangle {1\over \sqrt 3} &= X^2 - {1\over 2}(-1+0+1){X} + {1\over 3}(1+0+1)\\ &= X^2 - {2\over 3}\end{align}$$

Now normalise this vector : $$\langle X^2 - {2\over 3}, X^2 - {2\over 3}\rangle = \langle X^2, X^2\rangle -4\langle X^2, {1\over 3}\rangle + 4\langle {1\over 3}, {1\over 3}\rangle = 2-{8\over 3} + {4\over 3} = {2\over 3}$$

Thus $e_3 = \sqrt {3\over 2}\left(X^2-{2\over 3}\right)$

In conclusion Gram-Schmidt process applied to the canonical basis gives you the orthonormal basis : $$\left({1\over \sqrt 3}, {X\over \sqrt 2}, \sqrt {3\over 2}\left(X^2-{2\over 3}\right)\right)$$

*Note* : I highly recommend spending some time on it to make sure you understand the idea behind it and are confortable enough about it to do it yourself. One good exercise you can now do is apply the process on the same basis but treating the vectors in a different order (say $X^2$, then $X$ and finally $1$). This will give you a different basis than the one we obtained here.

Comment: How did you get <1,1> = 1+1+1 =3 ? Other than that very nice answer thank you.

Comment: @aprilanalysis: see my hint for how to apply the scalar product.

Comment: @mathreadler got it thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** I can help you with first part of the problem

*( First we **may** want to convince ourselves that we are actually dealing with an inner product here, but let's assume the question creator is not devious enough to lie about it being one. )*

Let us first define projection with the scalar product between two polynomials, $f$, $g$, having coefficients $f_2,f_1,f_0$ and $g_2,g_1,g_0$ respectively:

$$f(x) = f_2 x^2 + f_1 x + f_0 \\g(x) = g_2 x^2 + g_1 x + g_0 $$

$$\langle f,g \rangle = f(-1)g(-1) + f(0)g(0)+f(1)g(1)$$

$$\begin{align*}f(-1)g(-1) &= /\text{convince yourself}/ = (f_2-f_1+f_0)(g_2-g_1+g_0)\\
f(0)g(0) &= /\text{convince yourself}/ = (f_0)(g_0)\\
f(1)g(1) &= /\text{convince yourself}/ = (f_2+f_1+f_0)(g_2+g_1+g_0)\end{align*}$$

Now you can gather all terms up and simplify and you have the first piece of the puzzle done.

Comment: still not sure actually. because this gives sqrt(11) when computed ?

Comment: What? You don't even mention to me what you are trying to calculate then give me a random number. How would you expect me to be able to help you then?

Comment: sorry about that. For <1,1> = 1+1+9 = sqrt(11) with this method ?

Comment: how do you insert the <1,1> in place of the <f(x),g(x)>

Comment: what does <1,1> assign to the $g_2,g_1,g_0,f_2,f_1,f_0$ ?

Comment: okay got it sorry.

Comment: i think there's a typo also for the last bracket is it not supposed to be g1 instead of f1?

Comment: Yep, you are right.